# Getting host names and IP from router page - Python

Tags: python, networking

My objective is to find the hostnames and IP addresses of all the devices connected to a router to populate a combo box on my desktop app using a python script.

So far the only solution I have is to call nmap from my script and store back the result into a variable however I am not sure this is best way of doing it. Is there a more elegant and preferably platform independent solution?

Can I somehow get this info from router's admin page if I know the username and password? 
I am using a Netgear N150 wireless router

Comment: There is no standard for a "router page".  If your router supports snmp or hnap, there may be solutions based on **those**...

Comment: If the router has a REST API, or supports SSH and has a command that lists the IPs, then you can use Paramiko to get the info.

Comment: @AlexMartelli I thin I can enable snmap on my router. I am an using Netgear N150

Comment: Does this network have a DHCP server? Is it imperative that you get **all** IP addresses (i.e. even static ones)?